# Strange problem with loading images using Glide

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to get the avatar URL of the currently logged in user and then load it in this ShapeableImageView.
**XML Layout:**

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"/>
```

At first I wrote the code like this:

```
ShapeableImageView avatarImageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();

            // Get the user's avatar URL
            DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
            userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profile").getValue(String.class);
                        // Load avatar using image loading library
                        if (profileImageUrl != null && !profileImageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                            // Use Glide to load avatars
                            Glide.with(HomeFragment.this)
                                    .load(profileImageUrl)
                                    .into(avatarImageView);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle cancellation events
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Database read error: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

But there was a crash problem.

Then I changed this code：

```
if (profileImageUrl != null && !profileImageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                            // Use Glide to load avatars
                            Glide.with(HomeFragment.this)
                                    .load(profileImageUrl)
                                    .into(avatarImageView);
                        }
```

to this code:

```
if (profileImageUrl != null && !profileImageUrl.isEmpty()) {
    Glide.with(HomeFragment.this)
            .load(profileImageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.default_avatar) // Set backup image when loading fails
            .into(avatarImageView);
}
```

This default_avatar does exist in my drawable folder, but there is still a crash problem when running.

However, when I changed the code to：

```
try {
    Glide.with(HomeFragment.this)
            .load(profileImageUrl)
            .into(avatarImageView);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The crash problem has been solved and the user's avatar can be displayed normally. why is that?